# Lodash filter search in few element from array (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I have an object:

```
{
   1: {
         name: 'Adam',
         age: 12,
      },
   2: {
         name: 'Michal',
         age: 14,
      },
   3: {
         name: 'Jozef',
         age: 12,
      }
}
```

I tried using function `filter` from lodash:

```
this.knowledges = _.filter(this.knowledges, function (item) {
    if (item.category[1] !== undefined) {
        return arrayOfNumbers.indexOf(item.category[1].category_id) >= 0
    }
})
```

Variable `arrayOfNumbers` return array: `[1,3]`
so function filter should return:

```
{
   1: {
         name: 'Adam',
         age: 12,
      },
   3: {
         name: 'Jozef',
         age: 12,
      }
}
```

But it returns only first index:

```
{
   1: {
         name: 'Adam',
         age: 12,
      }
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You appear to be overwriting `this.knowledges` with your filter which is probably a bad idea. Your filter callback also may not return a value

Comment: so what does `this.knowledges` looks like? And what is your object represent for?

Comment: Hi, `this.knowledges` my all object (first from my query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lodash you can use [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#pick). Pick takes an object, and an array of properties, and generates a new object with the selected properties:

```js
const knowledges = {1:{name:"Adam",age:12,},2:{name:"Michal",age:14,},3:{name:"Jozef",age:12,}}
const arrayOfNumbers = [1,3]

const result = _.pick(knowledges, arrayOfNumbers)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

The `_.pickBy()` method works identically to filter for objects, so you can query the objects values, when you decide what to keep.

In this examples, I use `_.pickBy()` to keep all items with `age === 12`:

```js
const knowledges = {1:{name:"Adam",age:12,},2:{name:"Michal",age:14,},3:{name:"Jozef",age:12,}}

const result = _.pickBy(knowledges, o => o.age === 12)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want search by age ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#pickBy) like this:

```js
const knowledges = {1:{name:"Adam",age:12,},2:{name:"Michal",age:14,},3:{name:"Jozef",age:12,}},
      arrayOfNumbers = [1,3],
      result = _.pickBy(knowledges, (v, k) => arrayOfNumbers.includes(+k));

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

In vanilla JS, you could filter the the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and create an object using [`Object.fromEntires()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like this:

```js
const knowledges={1:{name:"Adam",age:12,},2:{name:"Michal",age:14,},3:{name:"Jozef",age:12,}},
      arrayOfNumbers=[1,3];

const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(knowledges).filter(([k, v]) => arrayOfNumbers.includes(+k))
)

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: ..remembering that `fromEntries` doesn't work on the usual IE and Edge browsers (which are dead, but it's still something you might want to know).

Comment: @a.barbieri IE doesn't support `const`, `Object.entries`, `fromEntries`, arrow functions or `includes`. This was meant to be an vanilla JS alternative. I was adding a lodash answer using `pickBy` but Ori Drori has provided a better answer.